# HOW to create color pulse on links on click while using particle.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, particles.js

I want to modify the particle.js for little change that when I click a new particle is created in it and when the particle is created it should send a color pulse to other particle through link from which it is connected and those particle do same when the pulse reach them can anyone help me to do modify it or any tutorial of it how to modify the particle.js for custom animation like link-pulse on-click

basically i know only dom javascript and the code of particle.js is complex that i have never seem in my life so can anyone help me out and explain what is in the code and how to modify for new animation like on-click-pulse-on-link

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.